# New Line Character In AT-COMMAND

Tags: at-command

I want to send a message with a new line character like `\n` using AT-COMMAND in text mode. How can I achieve this?


[This](http://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/at-cmgs-text-mode/) is an example of how to send using AT-COMMAND.

I've tried `\n` but it doesn't work. I want to send something like:

"THIS

IS

MY

MESSAGE"

Answer (score 0):

My first recommendation is always check out the manual for your modem hardware. Pretty much all of them have a manual covering supported AT Commands.

I would recommend sending the character code for . Once you have the message prompt ">" you can enter ASCII characters or codes as you so wish and will be interpreted as message content.